# Replacing missing values by group conditional on time window

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, na

I'm grouping by `subject_id`.

The variable acpa is measured on lines where `row_type == BIOBANK`.
I would like to replace the `<NA>` on the other rows, but only in a given time window, using the `index_date` variable.

Here is my table :

```
   subject_id index_date      row_type acpa
 1:        155 2010-05-12 BASELINE_info <NA>
 2:        155 2010-05-12 BASELINE_info <NA>
 3:        155 2010-05-12       BIOBANK    N
 4:        155 2010-05-12 PHYSICAL_exam <NA>
 5:        155 2010-09-29     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 6:        155 2011-11-30     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 7:        155 2013-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 8:        155 2014-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 9:        155 2015-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
10:        155 2016-08-31     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
11:        568 2012-04-07 BASELINE_info <NA>
12:        568 2012-04-07 BASELINE_info <NA>
13:        568 2012-04-07     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
14:        568 2012-04-19       BIOBANK    H
15:        568 2012-04-19 PHYSICAL_exam <NA>
16:        568 2013-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
17:        568 2013-12-12       BIOBANK    H
18:        568 2013-12-12 PHYSICAL_exam <NA>
19:        568 2014-04-27     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
20:        568 2014-05-22       RA_DIAG <NA>
21:        568 2014-05-28 PHYSICAL_exam <NA>
22:        568 2018-11-06       BIOBANK    L
23:        568 2018-11-06 PHYSICAL_exam <NA>
24:        568 2018-11-27     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
25:        568 2019-06-20     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
    subject_id index_date      row_type acpa
```

For instance, on line 3, `acpa` = "N".
I would like to perform something such as applying `na.locf()`, but only for rows that are between -180 and +365 days around the corresponding `index_date`.

```
library(date.table)
library(zoo)
TABLE[, acpa := na.locf(acpa, na.rm = F), by = subject_id]
```

How could I build a `rule` argument for `na.locf()` so it only fills the gaps in my time window ?

My desired output looks like :

```
   subject_id index_date      row_type acpa
 1:        155 2010-05-12 BASELINE_info    N
 2:        155 2010-05-12 BASELINE_info    N
 3:        155 2010-05-12       BIOBANK    N
 4:        155 2010-05-12 PHYSICAL_exam    N
 5:        155 2010-09-29     FOLLOW_UP    N
 6:        155 2011-11-30     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 7:        155 2013-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 8:        155 2014-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
 9:        155 2015-06-01     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
10:        155 2016-08-31     FOLLOW_UP <NA>
11:        568 2012-04-07 BASELINE_info    H
12:        568 2012-04-07 BASELINE_info    H
13:        568 2012-04-07     FOLLOW_UP    H
14:        568 2012-04-19       BIOBANK    H
15:        568 2012-04-19 PHYSICAL_exam    H
16:        568 2013-06-01     FOLLOW_UP    H
17:        568 2013-12-12       BIOBANK    H
18:        568 2013-12-12 PHYSICAL_exam    H
19:        568 2014-04-27     FOLLOW_UP    H
20:        568 2014-05-22       RA_DIAG    H
21:        568 2014-05-28 PHYSICAL_exam    H
22:        568 2018-11-06       BIOBANK    L
23:        568 2018-11-06 PHYSICAL_exam    L
24:        568 2018-11-27     FOLLOW_UP    L
25:        568 2019-06-20     FOLLOW_UP    L
    subject_id index_date      row_type acpa
```

In case of conflicts due to overlapping time windows, I would keep the value of the last (preceding) non-NA.

Answer (score 0):

My data-manager colleague proposed this :

start with forward projections.

```
    DT[!is.na(acpa), variable_t := index_date] # variable_t copied as the index date of the variable to impute
    DT[, acpa_c := na.locf(acpa, na.rm = F), by = subject_id] # locf for the variable in a new variable
    DT[, variable_t := na.locf(variable_t, na.rm = F), by = subject_id] # locf of the variable_time
    DT[, delay := as.numeric(difftime(index_date, variable_t ,units = "days"))] # calculating on each row the delay 
    DT[delay > 365, acpa_c := NA] # cutting off values above my threshold
```

then, same for backward projections.

```
    DT[, acpa_c := na.locf(acpa_c , na.rm = F, fromLast = T),by = subject_id] ### na.lofb, in the corrected variable
    DT[!is.na(acpa), variable_t := index_date] # reset of the temporary variable_time, so we can projet it backward
    DT[, variable_t := na.locf(ratio_t, na.rm = F, fromLast = T),by = subject_id] # locb of the variable_time
    DT[, delay := as.numeric(difftime(index_date, variable_t , units = "days"))] # delay
    DT[delay < -180, acpa_c := NA] # cutting off values above my threshold
```

if everthing ok, then remplace with new value.

```
DT[, acpa := acpa_c]
DT[, acpa_c := NULL]
```